# console.log()のコードでの出力は、F12のコンソール部分に出力されるという認識でいいのでしょうか？

Tags: javascript

以下のコードを書いたのですが、`console.log` の代わりに、`document.write` と書くとブラウザ上に山田太郎と出力されました。

これは、`console.log` の方は、ブラウザ上には出力されず、<kbd>F12</kbd> のコンソール部分に出力されるということで、単に読み込んだだけでは表示されないということでいいのでしょうか？

```
let user = {
  name:'山田太郎',
  age:27,
  address:'東京都'
}

console.log(user.name);
```

Comment: 質問に関係する内容はコメントに書くのではなく質問を編集して追記してください。また質問が次々代わってしまっています。一問一答形式のサイトですので、改めて質問を要約して書いてみてください

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) (Document Object Model) について勉強してみることをお勧めします。

**console** も **document** も**オブジェクト**です。それに対して `.log()` と `.write()` が **JavaScript メソッド**です。

- `console.log()` は [console オブジェクト](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/console)に対する .log() 命令を
- `document.write()` は [document オブジェクト](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Document)に対する .write() 命令を

意味するので、console オブジェクトに対する命令が、ブラウザーに読み込まれたウェブページを表す document オブジェクトツリーに、影響を与えることがないのは、当然であろうということになります。